# Is there a complicated select query to solve this problem

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, mariadb

i need to make a query on a table and inside this queryi would like to replace the value of "created_by" in the value of corsspende user "first_name"
becaus a user  create another user ,so i would like return the real name of creater instead of his id

i tried to get deeper in queries typess but the are so many ,inneer join, outer ,left join ,variable ,..
i don,t know which concept is the solution  [enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

You'll perform an INNER JOIN from this table back to itself:

```
 SELECT users.*, createdby.*
 FROM yourtable users
     INNER JOIN yourtable createdby
        ON users.created_by = createdby.id
```

In order to do this the each table in the `FROM` clause gains an alias. The first time we use it I'm calling it `users` and the second time I'm calling it `createdby`. This makes it obvious in the rest of the SQL which table is being referred to and why.

We join on the `created_by` of the first table to the `id` of the second. Essentially the second table contains the attributes of the `created_by` user.

You'll just have to swap the `yourtable` out for your actual table name and probably swap those `*` out with the actual fields you want from each table.

Comment: oh thnks for that ,but i need to do it complete :
my uset tables has the colum 'create_by' , i wan to returen this colmn with another value 
instead to return to the id of created users for the current user , i would like to return other value like 'first_name'
can you healp me please to formel such a query 
a query that take the 'create_by' and search for the user name of this id and return this name to the same colum or as a new variable

Comment: i tried thsis , but it dosen't work
**SELECT user.id , user.first_name, REPLACE(create_by,(select u.first_name from users as u where user.create_by=u.id)) AS create_by  FROM users as user**

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want. Please rewrite your question above and provide desired results based on that sample data you have pasted as an image.

Answer (score 0):

This should be handled by client side code instead of query because it causes confusion. If you really want it, you can just take first_name column value and return it as create_by like showed below:

SELECT first_name AS create_by FROM user;